# Create a webview preview of an HTML page inside another HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preview

Before you say this has already been answered in different questions, let me explain what I truly want.

I need to render a HTML page as a preview inside another main HTML page, and that part I can already do thanks to previous threads. My problem is I can't get a full webpage view, scaled into it's parent div, because my preview is in mobile view instead of a scaled full web view.

The following image shows what I'm looking for:
[image]

How can I achieve this type of preview? 
I've tried iframe, object tag, jquery load...

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: `<iframe>` is optional for a webpage inside a webpage. This allows you to create a preview of another webpage. EDIT: What was the result of '<iframe>'?

Comment: @EgMusic the result is similar to the result i got with <object>, it does render the page but in mobile-view.

Comment: could you please provide an image showing the result, so I could understand the problem better?

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing meta-viewport and any media queries that may be helping it to be responsive.Also don't forget to remove anything that is making the page responsive. You can also try to render page on server and serve a image screenshot instead if possible.
Making the containers height and width greater than space available can also work if the flow of webpage is natural.You will have to do this manually by force setting the width of container and allowing parent element to overflow.

Comment: I see what you mean but the page to be previewed is written in Bootstrap, so wouldn't disabling the media queries and etc ruin the page's structure?

Comment: i am not saying to disable  them I am saying you should add some of your own and use them wherever possible to protect the desktopview.

Comment: alright I'll try and give feedback later, thanks for your help!